# Elasticsearch : No field found in mapping while executing custom score script

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, groovyscriptengine

I've been struggling with this issue for hours now. I am trying to implement custom score in my search using script score (groovy).

Mapping :

```
{
"properties": {
    "m_skill": {
        "properties": {
            "actual_period": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "area_display": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "c": {
                "type": "double"
            },
            "capability": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "capability_display": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "order_wt": {
                "type": "double"
            },
            "skillarea": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "star_wt": {
                "type": "double"
            },
            "w": {
                "type": "double"
            }
            }
        }
    },
    "personid": {
        "type": "string"
    },
    date_of_creation": {
        "type": "long"
    },
    "phone": {
        "properties": {
            "c": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "v": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

(m_skill is an array)

Query :

```
{"match_all":{}}
```

Score script :

```
return doc['m_skill'].values.star_wt.sum()
```

Error :

```
No field found for [m_skill] in mapping with types [peopleworld]
```

But I don't get any exception when I try the same with "date_of_creation".
I found some people talking about the same issue but hardly any post has replies. Has anyone faced an issue like this. What am I doing wrong?

Another question, my formula is way complex then I wrote above. In simple language, it is like when a user asks for a set of skills I pick documents having asked skills and depending on their star_wt I award them a score which is used to sort the final result set. Is it a good idea to implementing the same using elasticsearch custom score?

Any help will be much welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a double quote on "date_of_creation" in your mapping. This may be causing the issue for you. I've added the mapping with validated JSON in this answer for you.

```
{
   "properties":{
      "m_skill":{
         "properties":{
            "actual_period":{
               "type":"long"
            },
            "area_display":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "c":{
               "type":"double"
            },
            "capability":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "capability_display":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "order_wt":{
               "type":"double"
            },
            "skillarea":{
               "type":"string"
            },
            "star_wt":{
               "type":"double"
            },
            "w":{
               "type":"double"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "personid":{
      "type":"string"
   },
   "date_of_creation":{
      "type":"long"
   },
   "phone":{
      "properties":{
         "c":{
            "type":"long"
         },
         "v":{
            "type":"string"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Donglecow for the effort but i finally figured out the issue. It wasnt the date_of_creation field. I was trying to access 'Object' in 'doc' which isnt possible as all it can give me is variables. doc['m_skill.skillarea'] did the trick.

Comment: This is the exact syntax I needed. Thanks.